# android:onClick is working slow for button

Tags: android, material-components-android, material-components

XML code for going from SignUp Page to Phone verification Page :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/signup_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn"
    android:text="Sign up"
    android:onClick="toPhoneNumber"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textColorLink="#CFC8C8"/>
```

Further Java File Code :

```
 public void toPhoneNumber(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this,SignUp2nd.class));
}
```

Comment: Add the code for `SignUp2nd`. The delay could be in the starting of that Activity

Comment: Hey @Ayush, your code is correct. This callback can't make it slow although. I reckon its something with your device/emulator or your activity itself. Adding more details to your question will help us to suggest more.

Answer (score 0):

**Ayush Dubey** try *addonclicklistner* instead on OnClick I hope this will help you.
here its documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button

**Example:**

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
             }
         });
```

Comment: Is it faster than using android:onClick?

Comment: No, it won't make any difference. Callback functionality is the same from the XML layout and from your class code.